# Parse huge json data to html with PHP is slow

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have one problem with HUGE JSON DATA. I get json data from backend with service and then I parse the data into HTML with PHP.

When I get raw JSON data it takes 2 second, but when I parse it into HTML, it takes too long, about 35 seconds. 
How can I accelerate parse time?

Find my code bellow. I use recursive function and for loops inside that function.

```
$allstructure=$this->allStructure();

    $str='<ul style="padding: 0px;padding-left: 5px;list-style: none">';
    for ($x=0;$x<count($allstructure);$x++){

        $str.='<li>'.$allstructure[$x]->name.'</li>';
        $str.='<li>'.$this->iterator($allstructure[$x]->child).'</li>';

    }

    $str.='</ul>';

    return $str;
}
   public function iterator($data)
{

    $str='<ul>';

    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)  {

        $str.='<li>'.$data[$i]->name;

        $str.='<ul>';

        $str.='<li style="display:flex"><input type="checkbox" class="rehbersecim"></li>';

        for($z=0;$z<count($data[$i]->listPosNames);$z++){

            $str.='<li style="display:flex"><input type="checkbox" class="checkqutu" name="vezife[]" value="'.$data[$i]->listPosNames[$z]->posNameId.'"><p style="width:230px;height:20px"><b>'.$data[$i]->listPosNames[$z]->posName.'</b></p> '.$this->createHtml($data[$i]->listPosNames[$z]->posNameId).'</li>';

        }

        $str.='</ul>';

        if(isset($data[$i]->child)){

            $str.=$this->iterator($data[$i]->child);
        }
        $str.='</li>';

    }

    $str.='</ul>';

    return $str;

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "When i get raw JSON data it takes 2 second". I assume "parse it into HTML" you mean when you loop over the entire JSON `$allstructure` to output HTML in PHP?
One obvious thing to do is cut the JSON into smaller chunks. If the data is HUGE, then I would argue it makes little sense to show such a long list to a user in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest name problem in the code above is the use of `for(...; count(...); ...)`. This forces PHP to do `count()` every time you go through the loop in question, and you have three of these. When dealing with large data, that will be murderously slow.

Instead of doing it that way, call `count()` one time for each loop, like so:

```
$structureCount = count($allstructure);
for ($x=0; $x<$structureCount; $x++){

    $str .= '<li>' . $allstructure[$x]->name . '</li>';
    $str .= '<li>' . $this->iterator($allstructure[$x]->child) . '</li>';

}
```

A good resource for this kind of thing is http://www.phpbench.com/. For this problem, it shows that calling `count()` each time through takes approximately 340% as long as calling it once, like I did above. Because you have 3 of these loops effectively nested, this one change means your app may be taking about 3.4<sup>3</sup> = 39 times as long as it should be.

Also, as [TomTom101 pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085341/parse-huge-json-data-to-html-with-php-is-slow/44085381#comment75193245_44085341), you probably don't want to show "HUGE" data to the user all at once. You should consider paging (i.e., showing only part of the data at one time).

Comment: I did as you said. But very little affected.

Comment: @AzerQurbanov Did you modify all three of your `for` loops? All three need to be changed, and you should see a very large impact. Just how "HUGE" is this data?

Comment: @AzerQurbanov Also, have you benchmarked how long the parsing itself takes? I'm assuming you're using `json_decode()`. How long does that take?

Comment: Yes I use json_decode. I request to the service using cUrl. it returns me back data in 2 seconds without parsing to HTML. Then i take the data and parse it to HTML using PHP (Laravel)

Comment: @AzerQurbanov Then something else is very wrong. It would help if you posted more information. Again, how big is the data? A link to a pastebin dump or similar would be helpful (but be sure you don't disclose any confidential information!). Also, be sure that the code that you posted is actually where the bottleneck is. You don't say what benchmarking you've done, so the biggest problem might be somewhere else entirely.

Comment: @AzerQurbanov phpbench.com doesn't let you enter anything. It shows you *types* of coding errors. You always should run your own benchmarks to find slow spots in your own code.

Comment: Data is confidential, that is why i cannot post it to you

Comment: @AzerQurbanov I've asked these questions several times, but you haven't answered, so I'll ask again: How "HUGE" is the data? How many megabytes? How many elements? And what have you done in terms of benchmarking any of your code? How do you know the code you posted is the slow part?

Comment: Json data is 66kb

Comment: @AzerQurbanov that's not "HUGE." That's not even large. Something is horribly wrong with your code - probably code you haven't posted - if parsing and displaying  that takes 35 seconds.

Comment: I removed this code from iterate function, then it loaded 2.5 seconds  '.$this->createHtml($data[$i]->listPosNames[$z]->posNameId).'

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
public function createHtml($id){

    $html1='<table style="margin-top: 0px;float: right">';

    $countDir=Direction::orderBy('id', 'desc')->count();
    $collection=Direction::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    for($x=0;$x<$countDir;$x++){

        $direct=$collection[$x];
        $say=Akt::where('direction_id', $direct->id)->count();
        $html1.='<tr class="az"><td><input type="checkbox" class="tick tickcount" name="checkn'.$id.'[]" rel="'.$id.'" value="'.$direct->id.'">
        <input type="text" class="form-control countbox  countbox'.$id.'" value="0" rel="'.$direct->id.'" style="float:right;width:50px">
        <input type="hidden" name="say" class="say" value="'.$say.'" style="width:50px">
        </td><td><input type="button" value="AKTS" class="btn btn-default" data-popup-open="popup-1">';

        $html1.='<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <div>
           <div style="width:220px;float: left;">
              <p style="margin: 0px !important;display:block;width:270px;height:40px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold">'.$direct->name.'</p>
                <table>';
        $countakts=Akt::where('direction_id', $direct->id)->count();
        $aktcollect=Akt::where('direction_id', $direct->id)->get();
        for($y=0;$y<$countakts;$y++) {

            $akt=$aktcollect[$y];
            $html1 .= '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="aktclass" name="akt'.$id.$direct->id.'[]" value="' . $akt->id . '"></td><td>' . $akt->name . '</td></tr>';
        }
        $html1.='</table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
    </div>


</div></td><td style="width: 300px">'.$direct['name'].'<p class="mesaj" style="font-size:10px;color:red"></p></td><td><table><tr><td><table class="prtable"></table></td><td><select class="prsecimn form-control" style="padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;width:50px !important"><option value="0">Seçin..</option>';

        foreach(Akt::where('direction_id', $direct->id)->get() as $akt){
            $html1.='<option value="'.$akt['id'].'">'.$akt['name'].'</option>';
        }

        $html1.='</select></td><td><!--<input style="width:50px" type="text" rel="'.$id.'" class="prsecimcount">--></td>
                                               <td><input type="button" rel="'.$direct->id.'" value="+" class="addprsecim form-control"></td></tr>
                                           </table></td></tr>';
    }

    $html1.='</table>';

    return $html1;

}
```